# Can I register official Nintendo controllers/accessories on Club Nintendo?

Tags: club-nintendo

[Club nintendo's site](https://club.nintendo.com/todo-product-register.do) says you can register game PINs and system serial numbers. Can official Nintendo controllers be registered for points as well or is it just consoles/games? I tried a number on my Wii U Pro controller but I have no idea if I picked the wrong number to input or if it's just not valid at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is games and consoles only.

Here is the list of eligible products:
https://club.nintendo.com/eligible-products.do